# How do I convert an existing road into an overpass in Cities Skylines?

Tags: cities-skylines

I've looked everywhere and the only answers I could find are related to placing new roads. Consequently I'm having to tear down existing highways and replace them with elevated highways.

What I want to do instead is simply elevate an existing highway so that the natural pathways remain intact.

Comment: Are you willing to use a mod? (PC only)